# firebird query join 3 table display all record

Tags: sql, join

I have 3 table that need to join but I want to show all on query

```
first table : itemtable
id itemname
1 item1
2 item2

second table : priceleveltable
id levelname
1 level1
2 level2

third table : relationtable
id itemid itemlevel price
```

and I want to show all record based on `itemtable` and `priceleveltable` become like this :

```
itemname      pricelevel  price
item1         level1      null
item1         level2      null
item2         level1      null
item2         level2      null
```

Can I query like that? I have tried left,right,inner join but it doesn't display record if no record on relation table

Comment: Where did you take column pricelevel? can you show the querry and the result?

Comment: sory , i mean pricelevel is levelname column on table 2...

Answer (score 1):

You would have to use a `full outer join` on Table3 and the join result on the first and second table.

```
SELECT * from firstTable as ft
INNER JOIN secondTable as st
ON ft.id = st.id
FULL OUTER JOIN thirdTable as tt
ON ft.id = tt.id
WHERE ft.id IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: thx for the query,but i can't join the id.cause the id is autonumber and not become relation between first table and second table

Comment: this my query,but still don't show like i want.. 
SELECT * from firsttable
FULL OUTER JOIN thirdtable
ON firsttable.id= thirdtable.itemid
FULL OUTER JOIN secondtable
ON secondtable.id = thirdtable.itemlevel